# pgfgantt: Start/End between time slots

Tags: pgfgantt

To be clear what I want to achieve I provide an easy example which points out what is not working yet.

This code:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[hgrid,vgrid]{1}{7}
\gantttitlelist{1,...,7}{1} \\
\ganttbar{}{1}{3.5} \\
\ganttbar{}{4.2}{5} \\
\ganttmilestone{}{6.2}
\end{ganttchart}
```

leads to this chart:

[image: mwe]

As you can see, each element (bar, milestone) has been aligned to a time slot. But I want these elements to start/end at exactly that place which I defined, so e.g. the first bar should end in the middle between two slots, the milestone should be at 6.2 (and not 6.0) and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments must be integers, fractions are truncated.

A simple way would be to multiply everything by 10 and scale down the gantt chart accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
   \begin{ganttchart}[
       hgrid,
       x unit=0.05cm,
       vgrid={*9{draw=none}, dotted},
       milestone left shift = -3.3,
       milestone right shift = 3.3
       ]{1}{70}
       \gantttitlelist{1,...,7}{10} \\
       \ganttbar{}{1}{35} \\
       \ganttbar{}{42}{50} \\
       \ganttmilestone{}{62}
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That's a shame that it doesn't support fractions.