# pgfgantt start on fractional unit (half month)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfgantt, gantt

I'm building a Gantt chart with `pgfgantt`.

I'm almost satified with the result but it seems that fractional values are not supported. For example the *Today* milestone is set on `2018-12-15` but it is shown at the end of December. The *Test* milestone is set on `2019-03-01` but it is shown at the end of March.

Is there a way/workaround to place it at the right, fractional x value?

I've found a similar question in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318877/pgfgantt-start-end-between-time-slots).

Is there a way to achieve the same with months instead of numbers?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{ganttchart}[
            vgrid,
            hgrid,
            x unit=2cm,
            y unit chart=8mm,
            milestone/.append style={xscale=0.2},
            time slot format=isodate,
            time slot unit=month
        ]{2018-12-01}{2019-06-30}
        \gantttitlecalendar{year, month} \\
        \ganttmilestone{Today}{2018-12-15} \\
        \ganttbar{Task 1}{2019-01-01}{2019-01-31} \\
        \ganttbar{Task 2}{2019-02-01}{2019-02-28} \ganttnewline
        \ganttmilestone{Test}{2019-03-01} 
    \end{ganttchart}    
\end{document}
```

[image: Gantt with non fractional dates]

I also have tried to use `time slot unit=day`, but then I'm unable to properly align the `vgrid` lines with the months.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{ganttchart}[
            vgrid={*{29}{draw=none}, dotted}, % how to align with months?
            hgrid,
            x unit=0.8mm,
            y unit chart=8mm,
            milestone/.append style={xscale=5.5},
            time slot format=isodate,
            time slot unit=day
        ]{2018-12-01}{2019-06-30}
        \gantttitlecalendar{year, month} \\
        \ganttmilestone{Today}{2018-12-15} \\
        \ganttbar{Task 1}{2019-01-01}{2019-01-31} \\
        \ganttbar{Task 2}{2019-02-01}{2019-02-28} \ganttnewline
        \ganttmilestone{Test}{2019-02-28} 
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fractional months but hgrid is not properly aligned]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proposal, which comes with a new option `fractional xshift` that can be added to the options. If you want to shift by half a month (or, more generally, by half a `x unit`, say `fractional xshift=1/2`, and if you want to shift by a day, use `fractional xshift=1/30`, and so on. (I also dropped the parts of your MWE that are not directly related to the problem.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{ganttchart}[fractional xshift/.style={%
    /tikz/xshift=#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfgantt/x unit},
     milestone label node/.append style={xshift=-#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfgantt/x unit}}
    },
            vgrid,
            hgrid,
            x unit=2cm,
            y unit chart=8mm,
            milestone/.append style={xscale=0.2},
            time slot format=isodate,
            time slot unit=month
        ]{2018-12-01}{2019-06-30}
        \gantttitlecalendar{year, month} \\
        \ganttmilestone{Today}{2018-12-15} \\
        \ganttbar{Task 1}{2019-01-01}{2019-01-31} \\
        \ganttbar{Task 2}{2019-02-01}{2019-02-28} \ganttnewline
        \ganttmilestone[fractional xshift=1/2]{Test}{2019-02-28} 
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It's a good workaround but still a workaround. I've edited my question to add another trial where I use `time slot unit=day`. It works out of the box, but then I am unable to properly align the `vgrid` with the months. Is there a way to achieve this? (I've also edited the question to use your MWE template)

Comment: @thibautg I do not know if that is so easy (but I am not an expert). Judging from `\def\gtt@vgrid@draw#1#2\relax...`  on p. 55 of the manual it might be difficult because, if I understand correctly, the grid is drawn in a loop n which the horizontal distance is constant. Drawing the vgrid by hand would just be another workaround. It is quite possible that there is already a built in possibility that takes care of that.

Comment: OK thanks. I've been able to do it by drawing a few `\ganttvrule` manually, but it is not very elegant. I will let the question open for a few days, and will then accept your answer if nobody provides a better solution ;-) I've already upvoted it though ;-)

Comment: @thibautg Yes, please wait. I am not at all an expert on `pgfgantt`. I just read the title of your question and thought that it is possible to create a style that does the fractional shift. Of course, I agree that your proposal is much more to the point. (But the `fractional shift` style may still be useful here and there, so I plan not to delete my answer at this point. And thanks for the upvote, I upvoted your question at the very moment you had an MWE.)

Comment: What if you need to end or start the gantbar in a fractional way?

Comment: OK, answering my own comment, to end a gantbar at a fractional position you can just use `\ganttbar[bar right shift=0.5]`